# should there be a syntax-only type of question for html / css

Tags: support

So professionally I manage a few devs and write code in several languages, have to debug others' code, and do business stuff.

I have down html for like 18 years but can't keep up with it. That being said, I often have to fix my own html or others. I find the fastest way to do this is just to create a fiddle, post a question on SO. Kinda like this: [how to get these two div's side by side in this container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33285450/how-to-get-these-two-divs-side-by-side-in-this-container/33285770)

I know a lot of these are simple but it seems like somebody also downvotes it for being a bad question or wants to close it (and honestly, I don't care about points or the scoring system). Why? It seems like there should be a tag that is like 'syntax-only'. To be honest, things like html change and people bring up good issues.

Comment: Any editor/IDE worth using will literally scream at you about bad syntax.

Comment: If I didn't have editing privileges, I'd downvote for the use of "thx" in the post.  But seriously, your formatting leaves much to be desired.  It makes your question look like a no-effort question and an easy downvote target.

Comment: that and including a jsfiddle without also including the code, instant downvote.

Comment: I use vim so will pass on an IDE but thx

Comment: I don't use vim but SURELY between highlighting and possibly a syntax checker plugin this becomes a non-issue....

Comment: What is meant by "syntax-only"?

Comment: @BoltClock - I was wondering that too. I'm certainly not an HTML expert, but aren't markup languages mostly about getting the correct syntax?

Comment: syntax-only? I want these side-by-side,what's css to get that done. I would consider 'syntax-only' rather than some long digression. It seems like people here Adobe Muse or FrontPage or  something. Not really familiar with nor that interested in it.

Comment: An IDE does not have to be a WYSIWYG. They are not necessarily one and the same. IDEs or Integrated Development Environment is, simply put, an environment specifically designed to make programming in a certain language (or multiple languages depending on the IDE) a lot easier by alerting you of mistakes that you are making (as well as other time saving things). You can get very minimal IDEs up to feature rich IDEs that are so bloated they can't move on their own. The point is that if you use the right tool for the job, you can solve your own problems easier.

Comment: so, I fully understand what an IDE is; I like vim and the terminal for web, used to use RubyMine, and use XCode for iOS. Presumably, the comment about an IDE laying out your HTML for you is something like Adobe Muse or Dreamweaver  I don't use those and really don't have any desire. None of the discussion addresses the point in the original question.

Answer (score 10):

No, there shouldn't be a syntax-only type of question.

Your question lacked code, as simple as that. I copied the html and css from your fiddle to a StackSnippet (fixed a typo in your html as well), guessed what you already tried and removed the noise at the end.

Your question is now answerable without the need for potential answerers to visit your fiddle. The fiddle should be seen as a support for the question, not the question it self.

Both question and answers have much more value now for future visitors and those visitors can have a one-stop experience.

Comment: After 726 questions and 54 answers,  OP should know that the relevant code needs to be in the post, and not only in external sites. I guess SO rules aren't communicated as well as they should be...

Comment: the original issue was spelled out in code. Personally, I prefer having it externally for questions like that. Honestly,the code was shipped to prod like 5 minutes after I asked the question on SO.

Comment: @timpone I'm happy that your question is solved, and I made sure your question  has more value for future visitors, even if jsfiddle goes dead. This day we are all winners.

Comment: thx - if you feel it's better with it inline, that's fine. I find the Orwellian groupthink of meta to be a bit ridiculous such as downvoting because of the use of "thx" or harping on vim or something. to each their own, I guess the original question is that it's fine to ask those types of questions.

Comment: Why, when some people are simply being told (by people agreeing with each other it's not a good idea) does someone always have to invoke Arken's Law (or Godwin's)?

Comment: Oh stop it, both of you. You disagree, that is fine. Please move on....

Comment: @rene: I mentioned it to the OP as a suggestion because people often wonder why suggestions will get brushed off, and invoking ridiculous arguments such as calling "people agreeing on something" as "groupthink", just makes their argument look silly and won't be taken seriously. I see it every day, and as soon as someone makes an argument like that, it's not taken seriously anymore.

Comment: @patricksweeney you really didn't get my last comment, did you?

Comment: @rene Evidently no.

Comment: I like that kind of humor ;)